# Saving image to firebase bucket doesnt have auth on link

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-storage

I am currently saving images as urls in my firebase database, however I need to convert these to saved images in the firebase bucket. I grab url, save it to firebase storage and then replace the image node with the new url to the firebase storage link which could then be put in an img tag.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');

const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

const bucket = admin.storage().bucket();
const request = require('request');

exports.saveToStorage = functions.database.ref(`/events/{eventID}`)
    .onCreate(snapshot => {

    const firebaseUrl = `https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/${FIREBASE_ID}.appspot.com/o/`;
    const filePath = snapshot.val().image;
    const fileKey = snapshot.key;
    const filename = filePath.split('/').pop();
    const firebasePath = firebaseUrl+filename;

    const remoteWriteStream = bucket.file(filename).createWriteStream({
        metadata: { contentType: 'image/jpeg' }
    });

    request(filePath).pipe(remoteWriteStream)
        .on('error', (err) => console.log(err))
        .on('finish', () => {
            console.log("Image saved successfully");
            //replace old image with new image path saved in firebase storage
            return snapshot.ref.parent.child(fileKey+'/image').set(firebasePath);
        });
});
```

The current problem is everything seems to work but the link obtained appears to not have auth on it and the image is not viewable from the link obtained from this method.

Can this be done this way or do I need to convert the image to binary data from the url and then upload to firebase bucket?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't try to manually build a download URL.  Those URLs are generated by Cloud Storage.  You can't simply invent one of your own.

If you need to generate a URL for a file that you add to Cloud Storage, you will need to do that either on the client or the server using a provided API.

You can generate a download URL on the client by [generating a download url](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_via_url) (linked instructions are for web, but you can do this on any client platform).

You can generate a download URL on the server by generating a [signed url](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls) using the Cloud Storage node SDK (the method is [getSignedUrl](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/1.7.x/File#getSignedUrl)).